# Is there a Unicode character for the Monero logo?

Tags: history

Is there a Unicode symbol for the Monero (XHR) logo, like ₿ for Bitcoin?

I'm looking for the best way to put the symbol on a website.

Answer (score 1):

There is a currency symbol for XMR: https://unicode-explorer.com/c/0271 but not the logo itself. There are many logo images online https://duckduckgo.com/?t=h_&q=monero+logo+png&ia=web and on the official website https://www.getmonero.org/press-kit/ you can use.

Comment: I didn't know ɱ was the XMR currency symbol. Thank you.